# How do you include pictures at certain positions in the body of the question?

Tags: support

## Specification

So, I ensure that my questions and answers are *only of the highest quality*. Nicely formatted, not like a wall of text and generally easy-to-read and understand. Plus, I'm deluded into thinking that high quality posts get me reputation.

However, I think my posts could be better. For example, [here's](http://pad3.whstatic.com/images/thumb/5/5a/Improve-Your-Writing-Skills-Step-19-Version-3.jpg/aid15870-728px-Improve-Your-Writing-Skills-Step-19-Version-3.jpg) a random picture. If I add that as a normal picture in my post:

[Picture Is Not Displaying http://pad3.whstatic.com/images/thumb/5/5a/Improve-Your-Writing-Skills-Step-19-Version-3.jpg/aid15870-728px-Improve-Your-Writing-Skills-Step-19-Version-3.jpg](http://pad3.whstatic.com/images/thumb/5/5a/Improve-Your-Writing-Skills-Step-19-Version-3.jpg/aid15870-728px-Improve-Your-Writing-Skills-Step-19-Version-3.jpg)

We can see that it is ***really*** big. I just wanted to have that **smaller** and to the **right** of my paragraph. So I figured out how to change the image size. We have to use the following snippet of HTML:

> `img src="http://example.com/sample.png" width="100" height="100"`

I'm no coder but that's pretty self explanatory. Here's my end result using that little bit of code:

http://pad3.whstatic.com/images/thumb/5/5a/Improve-Your-Writing-Skills-Step-19-Version-3.jpg/aid15870-728px-Improve-Your-Writing-Skills-Step-19-Version-3.jpg

So that's 200 pixels in width and 150 pixels in height. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) stack exchange meta page teaches us all the tags available for use that are in HTML. I don't understand this talk of attributes though, so I decided I'd ask my question on here.

**I think images would help make my posts nicer to look at**. That's why I believe images are a must-have for me.

---

## Question

> How can I have an image to the right of my body of text?

For example, I would have this paragraph I'm writing now and making extra long on purpose to serve as my example for how I want this to be done please do not comment on the grammar of this it is an example. So, to the right of this paragraph would be an image. A bit like when you drag and drop an image on Microsoft word next to your body of text and it auto formats it all for you.

Answer (score 2):

The official markdown syntax doesn't support right-aligning text or images in questions or answers, and it doesn't allow for multiple columns. Looking at the [markdown supported on this site](https://writers.stackexchange.com/editing-help), I see that tables do support what you're looking for but this only is the case in site documentation pages.

Does anyone know if there are workarounds for this?

Comment: I think it would require the use of CSS in order to accomplish this and I've not seen any used within the body of a question or answer, nor any way to add it as a user.

Answer (score 1):

To let text flow around an element, you would tell that element to `float: left` (or right) in that element's `style` attribute, thus:

```
<img style="float:left" src="...">
```

which would result in something like what you see below.

But since Stack Exchange does not allow the style attribute in questions or answers, there is no way that you can let the text of your post flow around an image.

---

[image]